# Accessing authentication-Token generate Error of couldn't find variable Token

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
 "user_data": {
"Authentication-Token": "uaotzNSfQRa_y_SS_aGx",
"X-SPUR-USER-ID": "66da3036-95a9-4dc4-b207-e46d238d3ace",
"email": "saleh@test.com", 
"first_name": "saleh",
 "last_name": "Jaan"}},
```

when i want to access authentication-token i generate error couldn't find variable Token, i'm Access like this `user_data.Authentication-Token`

Comment: show us your code!

Answer (score 1):

try this: `user_data["Authentication-Token"]`